# Setting alpha component for a predefined color

Tags: android

Is there an easy way on Android to set the alpha component of a color retrieved from `getResources().getColor(id)`?

For example, this is what I'm currently doing to change an existing color to 70% opacity:

```
DrawerLayout drawerLayout = ...;

int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.bgColor);
color &= 0x00FFFFFF;
color |= (((int) (0.7 * 0xFF)) << 24);

drawerLayout.setScrimColor(color);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using the helper class `Color`. You can easily retrieve the four components, alpha, red, green, and blue, and set it back with `Color.argb`, for instance. The class has only static methods, and you don't need to instantiate it. E.g.

```
int alpha = Color.alpha(color);
int red = Color.red(color);
int green = Color.green(color);
int blue = Color.blue(color);

int newColor = Color.argb((int)(alpha * 0.7f), red, green, blue);
```

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) you can find the documentation